# How java libraires from one EAR file could be accessed by another EAR file?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jar, weblogic, ear

I have two .Ear files, namely A.EAR and B.EAR. The first file is my application (around 1.5 MB) and the second one contains all the needed libraries such as Hibernate, log4j, etc. (Around 70 MB). How can I deploy them on weblogic in such a way that my code in A.EAR use libraries in B.EAR?

1. I cannot pack them into one .EAR file, coz I need to email my app every week. On emailing I just send the A.EAR file.
2. I cannot put the used libraries in `lib` folder of weblogic, because other apps use different library versions.

**Edit:**

Having find the right answer, it seems that [this Q on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5664189/how-do-i-create-a-common-component-in-weblogic) is somehow relevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could define B.ear as a shared application library and access it from A

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/web.1111/e13706/libraries.htm#i1065356

Answer (score 0):

This may not be a direct answer to your question, but I would question designing an actual deployable application's structure (i.e. splitting it across multiple EAR files) based on a need to "email the app every week".

To me, it seems dangerous to have 2 separate EAR files for one application.  I understand that you are saying B.EAR contains non-changing libraries (Hibernate, log4j).  However, by using them in A.EAR, they do inheritently become germaine to your application.  In other words, your application really is A+B ... A.EAR cannot live without B.EAR.

Instead, would it be possible for you to set up some sort of revision/source control repository (SVN, Git, etc) and use Ant/Ivy or Maven to manage your dependencies?

This way anyone who needed a copy of your application could access the repository, pull down the source, allow Ant/Ivy to resolve dependencies, and build.

Comment: Unfortunately, our application should be updated in another country that access to internet is limited there.